# Lista desplegable condicionada VBA

Tags: excel, lista, vba, macros

Tengo un problema con las listas desplegables condicionadas en VBA.

La formula:

```
IFS(L2=$M$2,B,L2=$N$2,Co,L2=$O$2,E,L2=$P$2,En,L2=$Q$2,I_T,L2=$R$2,O,L2=$S$2,P_B,L2=$T$2,Sp,L2=$U$2,SII)
```

Me funciona en excel pero por la naturaleza de la aplicación la necesito en VBA.

Esto es lo que estoy poniendo hasta ahora:

```
Agregamos la lista desplegable Title
    JT = Columns("E:E").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=IFS(L=""B2B Distribution"",""B"",L=""Contractor"",""Co"",L=""Electrician"",""E"",L=""End User"",""En"",L=""IT Reseller"",""I_T"",L=""Original Equipment Manufacturer"",""O"",L=""Panel Builder"",""P_B"",L=""Specifier"",""Sp"",L=""System Integrator"",""SII"")"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Necesito que según el valor (es string) de la columna L la lista desplegable sea una u otra.
Pero sigo sin poder implementar la formula en la lista desplegable. Alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: Mi táctica para las listas dependientes es: con un evento `Worksheet_Change()` me creo una hoja auxiliar que tiene en una columna el valor de la lista primaria en tantas filas como valores tiene la lista secundaria. Busco la primera fila y la última del valor de la primera en esa hoja, y le doy el rango de la segunda columna para la lista dependiente.

Comment: Gracias Damian, lo provaré

Comment: Ya lo solucioné de una forma un poco poco ortodoxa y sin VBA pero si alguien necesita la solucio que me contacte.

Comment: Pon la solución que has encontrado como respuesta, así podrás aceptarla y cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFS(L2=$M$2,B,L2=$N$2,Co,L2=$O$2,E,L2=$P$2,En,L2=$Q$2,I_T,L2=$R$2,O,L2=$S$2,P_B,L2=$T$2,Sp,L2=$U$2,SII)
```

Utilizar esta formula o cualquier otra mediante excel en Data>Data Validation>List

Hacer grupos para las listas y así no sobrepasar el límite de caracteres en la formula.